# How to get ip address of azure functions

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

How can i get the IP address of the azure function.

I would like to be able to send a request to the function and have the ip returned

I have tried this code, which hang and never completed / returned anything

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): void {
    console.log("HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    const ip = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] as string;

    context.res = {
        body: { ip },
        status: 200
    };
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're not using an async Azure function you need to call context.done() after setting context.res in order to return.

Microsoft does recommend you use [async functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2-v3-v4-export%2Cv2-v3-v4-done%2Cv2%2Cv2-log-custom-telemetry%2Cv2-accessing-request-and-response%2Cwindows-setting-the-node-version#contextdone-method).

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): void {
    console.log("HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    const ip = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] as string;

    context.res = {
        body: { ip },
        status: 200
    };
    context.done();
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

Comment: Didn't know about async vs non async, thank you

Comment: Using this code you provided, `ip` is undefined.

Comment: @GMN - are you running the function locally? The X-Forwarded-For header is likely only set when the function app is running behind a reverse proxy (e.g., deployed to Azure).

Comment: Ah good point i havent' tried it deployed yet.